# Solving $xy + x\log x \geq z$ with respect to x.

Tags: inequality

I have the inequality

$xy+x\log x \geq z$

I would like solve this equation in with respect to $x$ and essentially 
rewrite the inquality above as

$x \geq f(y,z)$.

What would be the simplest (and somewhat most accurate) $f$ that solves the problem above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very simple equation to solve. You can get

$$x = \frac{z}{W(e^y z)}$$

with $W$ the lambert-$W$ function.